¿Qué significa cuando en Visual Studio Code en el área de terminal dice: "el termino "" no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet o archivo de script?
Estoy aprendiendo Javascript en Visual Studio Code y copie un ejercicio de cómo crear una biblioteca, pero cuando lo terminé en el área de terminal me aparecieron muchos errores, la mayoría decían que "el término "tal" no se reconoce como un cmdlet, función, archivo de script o programa ejecutable.


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Copiaste un monton de cosas a un lugar donde no tenias que copiarlas, eso te paso...

El problemas que tienes es por estas escribiendo e intentando ejecutar tu código de javascript directamente en el terminal o cmd.
Solución:

Asegurarte de que tengas instalado  Node en tu computador

> node --version
v21.7.2


Descarga o copia todos los archivos del ejemplo que estas siguiendo en tu computador.

El proyecto de ejemplo del que estas siguiendo fíjate si tiene un archivo llamado package.json, en caso de ser afirmativo, posiciónate en la misma ubicación del archivo antes mencionado y ejecuta:


npm install


Identifica el archivo principal del proyecto, por lo general tienen nombre de index.js o main.js o puede estar con otro nombre random, una vez hecho eso en el terminal ejecutas el siguiente comando.

node test.js

Ejemplo:


Yo descargué Node, pero se ejecuta como un programa aparte, es así? A  veces cuando me salen errores en Visual Studio Code, hago los ejercicios en Code, y viceversa...Gracias por la ayuda.
